# Securing PHP for remote DB access

Tags: php, mysql

I've put together a web site with PHP and MySQL.  Originally they were all on the same host, but I've recently bought a new server so I've move the database to the new server and placed the old server in the DMZ as the web front end.  Now, it remote connects to the internal database server from the DMZ, runs a little slower but is otherwise great.

So, any dynamic web page that needs to access the database does a 'require' to a separate php file hosted on the web server that basically says;

```
<?php

$db_conn = new mysqli('IP_ADDRESS', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
        echo 'Connection to database failed:' .mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
        }

?>
```

This is on the web server and if this DMZ host is ever compromised, the username, password, and database name are fully exposed.  Is there a way to perform the 'require' to a remote .php file?

Comment: Doing a require to a remote file is even more insecure (unless you are using ssl/tls) because otherwise this data is getting freely transmitted over the internet.

Comment: This is not over the internet.  Like I said, one host is in the DMZ, the other in the internal network.

Comment: Well, if you can programmatically access the internal network from DMZ, then there is a good possibility anyone who can compromise the DMZ env could do the same with the internal network.

Comment: Your current setup is common. I'd suggest limiting the MySQL user to only the IP address of the web front end, which limits the entry vectors to that specific machine, and limiting the access to this db connection php file to only the web user

Comment: Yes, the account set up in mysql is 'username'@'web_server_ip_address'.  However the account pretty much needs full access to the tables in that particular db to do writes so if the web front end is broken into they can blow away the db.

Comment: I think with the right MySQL permissions this might fall under "acceptable risk." Plopping your config file outside the web root can provide some protections as well.

Comment: Hi esqew - It sounds like this is a pretty typical issue.  In my mind, I think the only way to secure the web server is to have a proxy set up in front of the web server.

Comment: @Kimomaru There is no possibility of having complete security. It is an impossible idea. It is possible to make something *very* secure but not invulnerable. In fact, your unusual idea may open more security holes than the accepted "norm." A better approach is to consider the inevitable and make regular daily (or hourly depending on the sensitivity of your data) backups of your SQL database.

Comment: @sjagr Okay, I'll move in that direction then.  Thank you for your input, I appreciate it.

Comment: @raidenace Not necessarily.  The DMZ host needs to use the mysql-client to connect to the internal db server at 3306.  So, port 3306 needs to be open between the DMZ and the internal host, no?  You can just blow away the db from the web front end this way.  The idea is that, hopefully, the front end will not be compromised so that the attacker would be in a position to run CLI commands from it.